# Best way for adding the universal custom cell for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created one custom cell for my universal application. I found two ways for implementing the custom cell for both iPhone and iPad :

1. The first way is we can create it programmatically :

   ```
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
   {
    //pragmatically setting bounds for iPhone components 
   }
   else
   {  
     //pragmatically setting bounds for iPad components  
   }
   ```

   or the second way is
2. Creating two separate xibs of custom cell for iPhone and iPad and load accordingly like:

   ```
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
   {
     //load iPhone custom cell here 
   }
   else
   {
     //load iPad custom cell here 
   }
   ```

So my question is , is there any other way to do it ? or which is the best way to do it ?

Comment: you should go with your second option so in future if there will be minor change for iphone and ipad you face no trouble to edit.

Comment: Yes ,,Second option will be a better approach,

Comment: With `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` you can register the appropriate nib file, so that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` always instantiates a cell from that nib file (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17412658/1187415). The advantage is that `registerNib` needs to be called only once per table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create cell with [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853) (programmatically or in xib). I don't know how your's cells differs in iPad and iPhone, but may be you will be able define constrains that will satisfy a claim at both devices.